# Does a goroutine necessarily run on a different CPU?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

The following excerpt is from https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#parallel.

> We launch the pieces independently in a loop, one per CPU. They can complete in any order but it doesn't matter; we just count the completion signals by draining the channel after launching all the goroutines.

```golang
const numCPU = 4 // number of CPU cores

func (v Vector) DoAll(u Vector) {
    c := make(chan int, numCPU)  // Buffering optional but sensible.
    for i := 0; i < numCPU; i++ {
        go v.DoSome(i*len(v)/numCPU, (i+1)*len(v)/numCPU, u, c)
    }
    // Drain the channel.
    for i := 0; i < numCPU; i++ {
        <-c    // wait for one task to complete
    }
    // All done.
}
```

Why does the article specify "one per CPU"? Multiple goroutines need not be executed on different CPUs. In fact, the last paragraph in the sub-section reminds the reader that concurrency is not parallelism:

> Be sure not to confuse the ideas of concurrency—structuring a program as independently executing components—and parallelism—executing calculations in parallel for efficiency on multiple CPUs.

Comment: The words "one per CPU" doesn't imply you can explicitly schedule them on a particular CPU, it just means you are launching a number of goroutines equal to the number of CPUs.

Comment: Do not confuse concurrency with parallelism.

Comment: @EndreSimo Please read my question in full; I think I make it clear that I do not conflate the two.

Comment: @JimB I see. Its usage under the "Parallelization" sub-section makes it seem as if the author is talking about scheduling each goroutine on a different CPU, even though that is probably not what he meant.

Answer (score 2):

> Does a goroutine necessarily run on a different CPU?

No, but it might.

Nothing to see here.

> why the article specifies "one per CPU"

It could have said 5 or 2. Really there is *nothing* of importance hidden here. This is just an example, not the specification of goroutine scheduling.

Comment: Could you also answer my other question, about why the article specifies "one per CPU"?

Comment: @unloadedmaterial, The author probably _assumes_ that no other program is competing for CPU resources, and that the operating system would naturally try to use all of the CPUs by assigning one runnable thread to each. Those would be reasonable assumptions if somebody were performing the experiment on a personal computer.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the article specify "one per CPU"? Multiple goroutines need
> not be executed on different CPUs. In fact, the last paragraph in the
> sub-section reminds the reader that concurrency is not parallelism:

goroutines are mapped with OS threads (M:N) and each goroutine can use a maximum of one thread at a time but you can not predict whether it is using the 1 CPU to execute all the 4 (GOMAXPROCS) goutines or it is use 2 cpu or 3 cpu or all 4 cpu.It is depending upon many factor's and all these complexity is hidden by go runtime